# Fields are empty error in magento singup

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a problem with magento, when u try to create an account or checkout your purchases, magento display a 'fields are empty' error ! even if your fields are not empty

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: can you check you registration page mandantory fields?

Comment: mandatory fields are filled, but it will error that they are not, no fields are empty